# perl - align widths of hex values

Tags: perl

For example, given a list of strings of hex values:

```
0
300
10b00
200
```

What would be a clean way of 'aligning' these to 4B width, like:

```
00000000
00000300
00010b00
00000200
```

Now I'm pretty much counting the length of each string and fill the extra `(8-len)` bytes with zeros and the code looks dumb. I've tried sprintf, `"%08x"` works nicely with decimals but gives the `Argument "A" isn't numeric in sprintf` error on hex values. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `%08s` format instead (as you need to format-print strings, not numbers):

```
my @l = ('0', '300', '10b00', '200');
printf "%08s\n", $_ for @l;

# 00000000
# 00000300
# 00010b00
# 00000200
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/hBdnYZT1).

Answer (score 1):

If your the input strings are not arbitrary strings but hex values, you should use [hex](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @values = qw(
    0
    300
    10b00
    200
    a
);

printf "%08x\n", hex for @values;
```

Output:

```
00000000
00000300
00010b00
00000200
0000000a
```